# How do I check if key exists in Couchbase?

Tags: php, couchbase

I've already thought of two methods which I don't really like:

1. Call to *touch(key, null)* inside try..catch.. and return false from
   the catch section. But then I'm changing the ttl which is not good
   for me.
2. Call to *add(key, value)* inside try..catch.. and return
   false from the catch section - This defects efficiency because I
   have to delete they key I've just unnecessarily added.

BTW, my environment is PHP.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Couchbase has not provided an `exists` method at this time, but u can use `add` and `delete` to do this stuff, this also work useful for Memcache/Memcached

```
public function exists($key)
{
    if ($this->object->add($key, true)) {
        $this->object->delete($key);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

https://github.com/twinh/widget/blob/master/lib/Widget/Couchbase.php#L118

Comment: the provided link is broken

Answer (score 0):

An easy way will be to do a get(key); if the key exists the value is returned, if not the operation returns null.

Is it ok with your application?

Note that since all the keys are in memory it is as fast to do a get when the key exists or not.

Comment: But what if the value of the key is null? The key exists but its value is null.

Comment: Alternatively the value could be megabytes in size; maybe you don't want to pull it needlessly.

Answer (score 0):

check into this example, taken from couchbase

```
  #retrieve the last access date/time of the script.
  #the key name is is the script name prefixed with DATE::
  $last_access_date=$cb_obj->get("DATE::" . $script_name);

  #handle the case where this is the first access to the script
  #and that key doesn't yet exist
  if($last_access_date == NULL){
  $last_access_date = "never";
   }
```

[Article Link](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-sdk-php-1.0/accessing-php.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing a simple `Exists` member as well.

In the .Net client you have `client.TryGet` which, however still will pull the item and when it returns `false`, it doesn't really mean it does not exists, just that it couldn't pull it (just tried to execute it with my nodes shutdown).

Again for the .Net client, but `ExecuteGet` would give you an `IGetOperationResult` which will expose e.g `HasValue`, but again pulls in the actual value.

Using a *view*? Perhaps a bit dirty, but you could have a view returning only the Ids, this would remove the need for retrieving the document as well. Not sure if it's really going to be performing better though.