# Fatal Error: "key does not exist on the server"

Tags: php, couchbase

Why does couchbase client for php throw a fatal error

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught exception 'CouchbaseException' with message 'The key does not exist on the server' in [CouchbaseNative]/CouchbaseBucket.class.php on line 196

Moreover there is no provision to check whether a key exists on the couchbase or not.

I am writing a wrapper for accessing the couchbase. I am half way through just to read the data from couchbase. But I found this issue; And when I am trying to access a non-existing key it throws fatal error and code crashes (doesn't execute further).

Below is the code (file 'couchbaseWrapper.php'):

```
<?php namespace CouchBaseWrapper;
 use \CouchbaseCluster;

class CouchDB {    
    private $couchClient;
    private $couchBucket;

    private function openConection(){
        try{
            $this->couchClient = new CouchbaseCluster(<COUCH_HOST>);
            $this->couchBucket = $this->couchClient->openBucket(<COUCH_BUCKET>);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function getKey($k) {    
        try{
            if(!$this->openConection()) { return false; }

            $res = $this->couchBucket->get($k);
            $data_rcvd = $res->value;
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e;
        }        
        echo "Outter Code";
        return $data_rcvd;
    }

}
?>
```

Require & Usage:

```
<?php namespace CouchBaseWrapper

ini_set("display_errors", true);

require_once('couchbaseWrapper.php');

$cb = new CouchDB();
$result = $cb->getKey("non-existing-key"); // <== Error
//$result = $cb->getKey("existing-key");   // <== Existing key No error

var_dump($result);
?>
```

In case of existing key no issues. It does print data received/fetched and prints the `Outter Code` as well. But if the request is for non-existing key then it crashes and it does not print the `Outter Code`.

I have tried the [exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754007/how-do-i-check-if-key-exists-in-couchbase) function. Following is the code (goes in file 'couchbaseWrapper.php'):

```
public function exists($key) {
    if(!$this->openConection()) { return false; }
    return $this->couchBucket->get($key) == NULL 
    && $this->couchBucket->getResultCode() == COUCHBASE_KEY_ENOENT;
}
```

Did not get anything out of it. I am using `Couchbase Version 2.0.7`. Any kind of help is most appreciated.

**P.S**: Already read the solution mentioned below; none of them worked

- [Get function when doc id not found crashes the code](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/get-function-when-doc-id-not-found-crashes-the-code/2352)
- [How do I check if key exists in Couchbase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754007/how-do-i-check-if-key-exists-in-couchbase)
- [How to check whether a document exists or not](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/how-to-check-whether-a-document-exists-or-not/3042)

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant, but in your very first line there is a typo (`CouchBaseWarpper` instead of (most likely?) `CouchBaseWrapper`)

Comment: @Burki Thanks for pointing it out. typo fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you're not catching *any* exception.

This code:

```
    try{
        // ...
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e;
    }
```

will never catch any exception, because it's namespaced under CouchBaseWrapper. Essentially, it is equivalent to writing:

```
    try{
        // ...
    }
    catch(\CouchBaseWrapper\Exception $e){
        echo $e;
    }
```

Which I'm assuming doesn't exist.

This will work though:

```
    try{
        // ...
    }
    catch(\Exception $e){
        echo $e;
    }
```

(Note the `\` at the start which takes you to the top level namespace where Exception is defined).

That should start to catch and echo the exception...

Then I guess you want to catch `CouchbaseException` (again, with the right namespace prefix), which I'm guessing is thrown – by design – when a key is non-existent.. or you can check if the key exists before getting its value (and return null probably if it doesn't).

Also note, *if* you want to catch multiple exception types, you should always catch \Exception last as they all inherit from it, it would overtake catching the inherited exception types.

Final note: If you don't want to prefix all your exceptions, you can just "import" them with e.g. `use \Exception;` like you did with `CouchbaseCluster`